# QT Pie chart labels are overlapping

Tags: qt, charts, qt5, qtcharts

I am using [Donut Chart Breakdown Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-donutbreakdown-example.html) to display some dynamic data in QT version 5. But in some case labels are getting overlapped, as in the screenshot given below. I there any way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: how many QPieSeries you have? show your code, I suspect that you have a lot of them

Comment: I have 4 main series and total 16 sub series divided among them.